# how to stop the page load again and again?

Tags: asp.net

I am creating online application in asp.net, there are some  dropdownlist on a page, when i select some item from the dropdown list page load is calling again, how can i stop this?

Answer (score 8):

Set `AutoPostBack="False"` for the list control. This will prevent the page from reloading when the selected item is changed.